# NuGet reference specification with an assembly not in lib subfolder

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

I have a fairly complex and large project that I want to attempt to package as a nuget package for internal use. I want to avoid copying files, because there are quite a few (150 MB+ of binaries). Instead, I am trying to point a package blueprint file to the files using the `<file ...>` element. Here's a simplified version of the file that I can reproduce my problem with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>AgentCore</id>
    <version>6.1.0</version>
    <authors>kkm</authors>
    <description>AgentCore</description>
    <references>
      <reference file="Utils.dll" />
    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="Kigo\bin\Release\Utils.dll" target="/lib/net40"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Whatever I try, I am getting the error:

> Invalid assembly reference 'utils.dll'. Ensure that a file named 'utils.dll' exists in the lib directory.

I tried suggestions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8764236/1149924), but to no avail.

Is it possible to avoid laying out the directory physically, as explained in the [NuGet documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#From_a_convention_based_working_directory), and use file references instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in the `target=` directory of the `<file ...>` element. It must not contain the leading `/`, i. e. should contain a relative path. The leading slash does not change package layout, but apparently confuses a reference evaluation device in NuGet. A correct line in the above specification should be

```
    <file src="Kigo\bin\Release\Utils.dll" target="lib/net40"/>
```

Wildcards also work (and that was my original intention):

```
    <file src="Kigo\bin\Release\*.*" target="lib/net40"/>
```

With the wildcard spec, a `<reference=...>` correctly accepts any binary packaged by way of wildcard expansion.